# Can a Bash script read from earlier in the current session?

Tags: shell-script

I didn't specify `stdin`, `stdout` or `stderr` because I mean all of them. Everything that is visible on screen and as many lines as it would scroll back, Everything that has been printed in the current terminal session ***before the script started*** and without having had to launch a background listener or something like that beforehand.

---

I thought about this while creating a quick script/function to delete the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` entry of a changed host fingerprint, which fortunately it took a few seconds figuring out I could do parsing `$?` and `history` and going interactive if there wasn't enough information. But *what if it was more complex than that*, I thought. TBH it does seem like a mayor security issue if Bash was designed like that, I don't expect it to be possible, still… No harm in asking. :)

Comment: i strongly suspect that it is dependent on the terminal program you are using

Comment: It's unclear what the issue is. Do you _want to_ have access to the terminal's scroll-back buffer or are you asking whether it's _theoretically possible_ to have access to the terminal's scroll-back buffer (of course it is), or do you have a specific issue relating to removing hashed keys from the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file (you are aware of the `-R` option to `ssh-keygen`, right?)  Consider updating your question to make the main issue clear, and also consider adding the correct tags.

Comment: I notice that you have asked several questions by now but haven't accepted _any_ of the answers that you have received. Consider accepting the most helpful answers to each question. Doing so will mark the issue as resolved, and it will also increase your chances of getting help in the future. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers